# Vectorising scalar code

Tags: matlab

suppose that we want to calculate  Stirling approximation to  n  factorial in matlab,simple calculation for arbitrary  n value will be

```
sqrt(2*n*pi) * exp(-n) * n^n * exp(1/(12*n))
```

but what we want to work with arrays too?for example  our  code

```
stir([2 3 5])
```

should work and  have to  give answers like this

```
ans =

  2.0007   6.0006   120.0026
```

how can i do such that,function can work with arrays?

Comment: You could also do this without inserting element wise operators in the function. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add element-wise operators:

```
stir=@(n)sqrt(2*n*pi) .* exp(-n) .* n.^n .* exp(1./(12*n));
```

Now stir([2 3 5]) will work.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this without inserting element-wise operators in the function.

```
% Create a function handle which takes one argument n and calculates the stirling approx.
stir = @(n)sqrt(2*n*pi) * exp(-n) * n^n * exp(1/(12*n))

% Use "arrayfun" to perform the calculation on each array element.
arrayfun(stir, [2 3 5]);
```

This approach will not clutter up the function with element-wise operators.

Answer (score 1):

You need to investigate the element-wise operators, e.g. `.*` and `./`. See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html.

Comment: i know this one,but  from the question it is clear that,i want to  access  each element  and calculate  it's stirling's approximation,sorry but it is not much helpful for me

Comment: @dato: If you want to the above code to work on each element of an array in parallel, then you definitely need to convert it to use `.*`, `./`, etc.  If this is not the problem, then please edit your question to make it more clear.